# how to access of the first TD of the clicked TR for Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table; when I click on a tr I need to change the class of the first td in that; for some reason I need to use onclick! I dont know how to pass the first td of the clicked tr or if I pass the clicked tr>I dont know how to change the class of the first td of that class;

I have tried the following which is not woking; could you please help me in this regard?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/8RF5r/2/

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="myFunction(this.id)">
        <td></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>        
    </tr>

    <tr onclick="myFunction(this.id)">
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="myFunction(this.id)">
        <td></td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>        
    </tr>    
</table>


function myFunction(id)
{
 if (id.hasClass('checked')) {
            id..siblings(":first").addClass('checked');
        } else {    
            id.siblings(":first").removeClass('checked');
        }
}
```

PS: I know my code is not right; I just need your help; I dont know how to pass the first td of the clciked tr or how to get the first td or the clicked tr if I pass the clicked tr

Comment: you are passing the id, which would be a string so there would be no `hasClass` function it.

Comment: YEs how can I pass the first td of the clicked tr?not ID!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing the id, which would be a string so there would be no `hasClass` function for it. Just pass `this`, than wrap it in the function, also you can just toggle the class with [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
<tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>        
</tr>
```

JS

```
function myFunction(element){
   $(element).find("td:first").toggleClass("checked");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RF5r/4/)

Though it would probably be easier to just set a listener instead of using attribute onclick

```
$("tr").click(function(){
   $(this).find("td:first").toggleClass("checked");
});
```

OR

```
function myFunction(){
   $(this).find("td:first").toggleClass("checked");   
}

$("tr").click(myFunction);
```

In both cases the keyword `this` will be a reference to the clicked element. From there you just use the correct selector to select the first td then toggle the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery as a tag to this question, I assume you are ok using jQuery. In that case you can attach a click listener to your row, find the first td child of that row and change the class.

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var myTD = $(this).find("td:first");
    if(myTD.hasClass('checked')) {
        myTD.addClass('checked');
    } else {
        myTD.removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```